# Get values from one list where a value is present in another list

Tags: javascript, caml

I have 2 lists with a parent child relationship.

**List A**

```
ID    Title
----------------
1     First
2     Second
3     Third
```

**List B**

```
ID    Title    List A Lookup
----------------------------
1     Value 1   1;#First
2     Value 2   1;#First
3     Value 3   2;#Second
4     Value 4   2;#Second
5     Value 5   2;#Second
```

What I'd like to do is identify all of the items in List A that have child records in List B.  Given the above data, the results should be:

```
ID    Title
----------------
1     First
2     Second
```

CAML has an [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/ff625761.aspx) operator, but it looks like that requires you specify the individual values, rather than using another query as the source of the values.

In SQL, I'd write this:

```
SELECT ID, Title
FROM ListA
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ListALookup FROM ListB)
```

Is this possible?  Or do I need to query all items from List B, loop through, and track the distinct List A values from there?

If there is a solution to this outside of CAML, I'm open to that as well, as long as I can implement it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way it to create a lookup column from 'List A' to 'List B' and as column select 'List A Lookup (Count Related)' (This will only show up because 'List B' is already related to 'List A' through this column).

Now you have a column containing how many items in 'List B' each value from 'List A' have relating to it and can filter on that being greater than zero.